# Parser error in using inhertis from default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have designed a `mypanel.aspx` as a default page in my project. I used telerik panel and have given all the controls within that panel. At the `vb page` i couldn't access the controls like "textbox,button". From some reference i used the `Namespace` for the `mypanel.aspx`. But after using that i got a parser error on the web page as

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 


Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the  following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'mypanel.panel' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="panel.aspx.vb" Inherits="mypanel.panel" %> Line 2:   Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>


Source File: /panel.aspx    Line: 1
```

Error line in **mypanel.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="panel.aspx.vb" Inherits="mypanel.panel" %>
```

**mypanel.vb:**

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Namespace mypanel.panel
    Partial Public Class panel
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        End Sub
        Protected Sub btnsumbmit_click()
            Response.Redirect("empty.aspx")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Change name of your class because it is same as your namespace. In inherits you need to write the name of class not the namespace so either change name of your class or try this

```
 Inherits="mypanel.panel.panel"
```